# pandas apply to attribute instead of function

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

Is it possible to use df.apply to get an attribute as opposed to running a function? I want to retrieve the year from a date to perform a groupby. For example ..

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [datetime.datetime(2010,1,1)+datetime.timedelta(days=i*15) 
for i in range(0,100)]})
```

This works ..

```
df['year'] = [d.year for d in df['date']]
```

This also works ..

```
df['year'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
```

But this does not ..

```
df['year'] = df['date'].apply(year)
```

Nor does this ..

```
df['year'] = df['date'].year
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Use the `.dt` accessor when accessing on a series object - `df['date'].dt.year`.

Comment: Aside from the above comment why would this `df['year'] = df['date'].apply(year)` work? `year` would need to be a defined object or method to apply on each row which is it isn't hence why you needed the `lambda`

Comment: @NickilMaveli thanks. Is this datetime specific? If I had another non datetime object that I wanted to access an attribute for, do I use lambda or is there a shortcut?

Comment: In that case, converting your non-datetime series to datetime via `pd.to_datetime()` would be feasible so that you can then use the `.dt` accessor on it rather than resorting to a `lambda` function in `apply` which would consume much more time if the size of your `DF` is large.

Comment: What about a non datetime object at all? Another object entirely -- say with an attribute like `.foo`.

Comment: I didn't quite get you there. Can you maybe rephrase this better or edit your question to describe this case? If you meant whether `.dt` accessor is specific to only `datetime` objects, then the answer is yes.

Comment: Yup exactly, I meant whether there was a more generic way of accessing attributes or methods of objects in a Series that was not `datetime` specific. I guess that is `apply` and `lambda`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be happy to know there is an entire set of functionality built to provide an abundance of date attributes. You can use the [`dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) accessor to get many datetime attributes. It can only be used on pandas series or indexes that are date types.

You can see all the available attributes with `dir(df['date'].dt)`. Here they are printed out below. In your case simply use `df['date'].dt.year`

```
'ceil',
 'date',
 'day',
 'dayofweek',
 'dayofyear',
 'days_in_month',
 'daysinmonth',
 'floor',
 'freq',
 'hour',
 'is_leap_year',
 'is_month_end',
 'is_month_start',
 'is_quarter_end',
 'is_quarter_start',
 'is_year_end',
 'is_year_start',
 'microsecond',
 'minute',
 'month',
 'nanosecond',
 'normalize',
 'quarter',
 'round',
 'second',
 'strftime',
 'time',
 'to_period',
 'to_pydatetime',
 'tz',
 'tz_convert',
 'tz_localize',
 'week',
 'weekday',
 'weekday_name',
 'weekofyear',
 'year'
```

Comment: Thanks Ted. I was hoping for something not `datetime` specific, but works for my immediate problem.